# Alternatives to tabs in strings when using Python wxWidgets wxlistbox

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

As noted here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html

> Notice that currently TAB characters in list box items text are not handled consistently under all platforms, so they should be replaced by spaces to display strings properly everywhere. The list box doesn't support any other control characters at all.

So far in my experience while using Python 2.7 32-bit in Windows 7, using \t within the string of a wxListBox selection has no effect; as expected

I have a bunch of rows from the database and I have multiple columns that I want to display (and eventually use on selection of one or more row) within a row in wxListBox. For now I am using spaces as recommended as the delimiter between values in the string. However, this is not really ideal since the columns are variable length.

**Is there an alternative to the \t that is not a simple delimiter?** The point here is to have all of the columns for each row presented neatly i.e.

```
    column1        value1            value2
    column442142   values24234234    val2
```

rather than

```
   column1        value1        value2
   column442142        values24234234        val2
```

wxGrid comes to mind but I don't think that would work for me because I don't want to be able to select specific cells within a row (I can't seem to find the function to disable that), I only want the user to be able to select a row or multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to use [wxListCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html) for the simple multicolumn data display or [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) if you need more features.

FWIW you can use [wxGrid::SetSelectionMode()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html#a9da14b2045b0292cecc8e91b65993d29) with `wxGridSelectRows` argument to disable cell selection but `wxGrid` is arguably still not the best control to use for something like this.

See [this slide from my lectures](http://www.tt-solutions.com/img/slides/tables_comp.pdf) for a brief summary of different controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "    4 whitespaces replace a tab"

print "%20s"%some_string_padded_to_20_chars
```